# Abort not aborting

Tags: programming, interruption

I have a relatively simple bit of code that looks like the following:

```
---some code here---
If[statement, Abort[]];
---more code following---
```

However, while `$Aborted` appears as output, the evaluation of the rest of the cell does not abort, continuing execution of code beyond the `If` statement. How do I actually get the running cell to cease evaluating the rest of the cell?

**Edit:** It seems that one way to accomplish this is to wrap the entire cell in parenthesis, e.g., but this is a fairly ugly solution, especially with auto-formatting turned on (my cell has many lines of code, and the parenthesis are huuuuuge). Anyone have a more elegant solution?

```
(
---some code here---
If[statement, Abort[]];
---more code following---
)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This question [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625648/how-to-abort-evaluation-of-a-sequence-of-inputs) on stack overflow. However we will summerize some of the answers given there on our new *Mathematica* site.

### Wrap In Compound Expression

One suggestion by Michael Pilat, given there was to wrap your lines in `CompoundExpression`, e.g.

```
(
   Print@Range[5];
   Abort[];
   Print@Range[5];
)
```

> During evaluation of In[39]:= {1,2,3,4,5}
>
> ```
> $Aborted
> ```

If you mind the formatting of parenthesis, you could explicitly use the `FullForm` of `CompoundExpression` like this:

```
CompoundExpression[
   Print@Range[5],
   Abort[],
   Print@Range[5],
]
```

### Use of `$PreRead`

Suggested by Alexey Popkov:

```
In[1]:= $new$PreRead = False;
AbortAllPendingInputs := 
  AbortProtect[If[! $new$PreRead, $new$PreRead = True;
    $TimeOfAbort = SessionTime[];
    last$PreRead = ToString[Definition[$PreRead], InputForm];
    ClearAll[$PreRead];
    $PreRead := If[TrueQ[SessionTime[] - $TimeOfAbort < 1], "",
       $new$PreRead = False;
       ClearAll[$PreRead];
       If[last$PreRead === "Null", #, 
        ToExpression[last$PreRead]; $PreRead@#]
       ] &;]];

In[3]:= f := CheckAbort[Pause[10], AbortAllPendingInputs; Abort[]]

In[4]:= While[True, f]
While[True, f]
While[True, f]
```

> Out[4]= $Aborted

Note that this solution will need to be modified if you use `$PreRead` for anything else.

### Use of CellEvaluationFunction

`CellEvaluationFunction` gets the `BoxData` expression, before it is even split. Just assigning something like `CellEvaluationFunction:>ToExpression` seems to do the trick.

You can set it as an Input cell style, or as a notebook option, or front end session option, or however you like

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, CellEvaluationFunction :> ToExpression]
```

However, you lose the multiple outputs in those new lines when you don't use ;. This can probably be solved but I don't know very well how CellEvalutionFunction works, and how can it receive a box structure, default to Identity but expect to return an expression. Edit should you come up with any improvements

Comment: Since you tagged this community wiki, would you mind if others were to port over some of the suggestions from the stack overflow question here? With appropriate credit and whatnot of course!

Comment: @nixeagle No, of course I don't mind! That was the idea.

Comment: Alright, I'll go ahead and work on that. Plus I ought to suggest to @Guillochon that using more smaller functions might help with the concern raised in his **Edit**.

Comment: Alright, done editing this. If anyone else can make the answer clearer or wants to volunteer a 3rd (possibly better!) solution, please do so. As a side note, as I don't know where else to mention this, do we want to keep that _abort_ tag on this question?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, I just saw that your answer was a community wiki and that in the link you provided someone suggests in comments a CellEvaluationFunction approach, like my answer. Should I delete it and put it in the community answer?

Comment: @Rojo This is entirely up to you, but if I were you, I would do this, just because this would nicely fit into the structure of the above CW answer. I think, the main question to ask is which way will benefit those who come to this page in the future the most. One well-structured answer, particularly being a result of joint efforts of several people, seems to me easier to comprehend than several disjoint ones.

Comment: Agreed. Btw, have you read my comments on the bounty question's answer of Mr.Wizard? There's a bottleneck in his previous usage of `StringReplaceList` (without those `Block`s) that has been worked around, but we don't understand why it exists.

Comment: @Rojo No, I haven't. B.t.w., I've solved this precise problem years ago, by a method similar to one of Mr.Wizard, and I remember that in my solution, the major speedup was due to the memoization: I was memoizing branches of the split tree. Didn't have time to review and post it, but you can use this hint if you want. I was splitting arbitrary sentences given English dictionary (built in M). As to the speed differences, here is my guess (no time to verify now): by using `Block`, you changed the way you build your tree from depth-first to breadth-first. The speed-up is likely due to the ...

Comment: @Rojo ... fact that with the breadth-first approach, you don't interleave pattern-matching (`StringReplaceList`) with the top-level code that much, so it should work well for "horizontal" trees which have many leaves at each level but not so many levels. I can't say whether or not this is really the major factor in speed improvement though.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the documentation FrontEnd uses CellEvaluationFunction -> Identity
and not ToExpression. Still the [example](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Abort.html) works and

Print[a]; Abort[]; Print[b]

aborts properly (not printing b) because all statements are in one line.
Apparently it is the line breaks which break up the cell into individual commands, not the semicolons. So there must be another way "fixing" this.